# dir-paginate/ng-repeat index resets to 0 when moving to the next page

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, pagination

I am using the following to display TV shows on a table:

```
dir-paginate='show in shows | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | itemsPerPage:10'>
```

I also use this to set up pagination controls

```
<dir-pagination-controls max-size='5' direction-links='true' boundary-links='true'></dir-pagination-controls>
```

However, I found that the index resets back to 0 when I change the page. I have the ability to delete a row from my table `ng=click='removeShow($index)'`. So if I was to delete the first row on the second page, it deletes the first row on the first page instead because of the index.

```
$scope.removeShow = function(index)
{
    $scope.post_data.id         = $scope.shows[index].id;
    $scope.post_data.watched    = -1;
    $scope.post_data.action     = 'REMOVE';

    $scope.shows.splice(index,1);

    var data = JSON.stringify($scope.post_data);

    $http.post("get_tv_schedules.php", data)
    .then(function(response)
    {
    }, 
    function(response)
    {
    });      
}
```

Then in `get_tv_schedules.php`

```
$sql = "delete from tv_schedules where id = $data->id";

if(mysqli_query($connection, $sql))
{
  echo "OK";
} 
else
{
  echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($connection);
}
```

Is there a way to continue the index from page to page?

Comment: It would be good if you post your controller code. How do you delete a row? What are you taking as index for deleting the row? Did you implement any function for the `on-page-change` attribute of this directive?

Comment: @lealceldeiro I've updated my post. I didn't implement any function no, I simply changed `ng-repeat` to `dir-paginate` and added the pagination controls show above.

Comment: Did you check in your `$scope.removeShow` function what's the value of index? Is the correct one?, the want you want to delete? I ask this just in order to isolate the problem, whether it's in the front-end and not in your back-end service.

Comment: @lealceldeiro `$scope.shows` is an array of objects. On the first page, the index is correct. It deletes the one I choose to delete. On the second page, if I was to delete the top row of that page it deletes the record on the first page since the index resets to 0 when the page changes. So if I tried to delete the first row on the first page I get `$scope.shows[0]` as the index. Since it resets the index onto the next page `$scope.shows[0]` then it just deletes the value indexed at 0 even though it's on the next page.

Comment: I've worked a lot with this directive and I'm pretty sure I can help you, but  I think It would be better if you could make a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (jsfiddle, plunker or similar) in order to reproduce the exact problem. Use a mock data if needed and we shall see what's the problem here :). **I don't know** whether you're paging with async data or not, so maybe you have all records on frontend or just the one being shown in the current page. This is important in this case.